# Can I enter a mission without a primary weapon?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

When preparing for insertion, can I select no primary weapons, simply arming myself with a secondary and then collecting weapons in the field?

If so, how?

Comment: I haven't been able to do so, so I doubt it. Can't find anywhere to confirm it though.

Comment: Why would you want to do this though?

Comment: It costs a (very small) amount of money, I can get guns from enemies, I haven't used a primary weapon in several missions. Self congratulation/amusement?

Comment: @Bucky If you have to ask this question, you are not familiar with the hardcore fans of this franchise...

Comment: I often found myself in this situation too - not needing a primary in the field (relied mostly on tranq sniper rifle and the tranq pistol).  To save on costs, I just selected the base machine gun (the one at the top of the list), and left it at the lowest star ranking.  That way, it only cost 90 GMP or so per sortie, and no additional resources.  I think that was the cheapest way to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot, in the sortie screen when you can choose to not have a weapon the choice of `[none]` is present in the menus above the gun choices. For primary, secondary, and arm, the option is not there.

Comment: So... Big Boss has to be 'armed' to start the mission ;)

Comment: as a side note, missions unlocked later in the game can have the [SUBSISTENCE] tag, these start you out with no weapons and no camo, just your arm

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer Oh god, I'm so hyped for those missions now. That sounds like a fun as hell challenge. These are things that I don't mind getting spoiled because it just makes me more excited. I just hope face paint is unlocked in the head options before those missions come around so I can put on my war face while playing Naked Snake with no gear.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer: Oh, that's awesome. Thanks!